# C&C on xubuntu using wine/playonlinux

Tags: wine, xubuntu, playonlinux

I have Xubuntu 12.04 running on my notebook. One thing I would like to have working is C&C, the modded version from cncnet.org.

I found these websites but all I try, it simply does not work for me.
http://funkyfr3sh.cncnet.org/playonmac_playonlinux/

I have saved 1 error report:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zemjzgpi2vg64yq/backtrace%20wine%2020140209.txt

I don have a clue what is going wrong and how I can solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now have a different notebook which easily runs C&C using Wine. The other notebook is not used anymore.